# Notification in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everytime a registerd user updates their profile, I would like the administrator to get an email notification about this.

In Drupal notification module will do this need

How can this be done in rails?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [ActiveRecord::Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html).

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    observe :userprofile
    def after_save(userprofile)
      Notifier.deliver_comment("bofh@buddybetting.com", "The profile for #{userprofile.username} has changed.", userprofile)
    end
end
```

Comment: This is using ActionMailer (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) to do the actual email sending.